# Will Task.WhenAny unregister continuations on unfinished Tasks?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, mono, task-parallel-library, async-await

Consider a class which has some kind of lifetime. During this lifetime, an event may occur any number of times and the event is signaled through completion of a task (which is renewed after an event). The object may also be shut down, ending its lifetime. Shutdown is also signaled through completion of a task. It may as well live forever.

Now consider some kind of asynchronous workflow modelling the lifecycle of the object:

```
//will be completed on Shutdown. Is the same object for the entire lifetime.
Task shutdownTask = ... 

while(true)
{
    //will be completed when the event occurs. Is different on each loop.
    Task eventTask = ... 

    if (await Task.WhenAny(shutdownTask, eventTask) == eventTask)
    {
        //Event has occured
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        //Object has been shutdown. React and leave.
        ...
        return;
    }
}
```

An example for eventTask could be asynchronously dequeueing an object from an async Queue.

Intuitively I find nothing wrong about modelling the lifecylce of an object this way. However, The object may live forever and an unbounded number of continuations are registered on shutdownTask. Or are they? Will continuations be unregistered or will the app eventually blow up? Is there a cleaner pattern to model such a control flow?

Comment: You're adding more continuations after the task is completed?  "adding" a continuation after a task is completed just executes the delegate synchronously right then and there.

Comment: In my code example, I'm not adding continuations to a completed task. Not even Task.WhenAny does.

Comment: Yes, as soon as any of the tasks complete the continuation will be removed from all other tasks.  In you example, if `eventTask` completes, that continuation will be removed from `shutdownTask`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the continuation will be removed from all the given tasks when any one of them fires.

Comment: Doesn't canceling a continuation do pretty much the same thing?

Comment: Is there any official documentation on this? I just browsed the Mono sources and it seems that the desired property does not hold there. I added the 'mono' tag to the original question.

Comment: It is an undocumented implementation detail of .NET's `WhenAny`. Open it up in ILSpy. I guess Mono doesn't technically need to reproduce undocumented behavior, but they'd probably consider it a valid bug if you reported it.